# Use PDO within Jqgrid.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, jqgrid

I've been having issue manipulating my data within my grid and as told to change my connection type from Mysql to PDO so that's what i'm trying.

When I run my data file I get data but for some reason it isn't reaching and displaying on my grid.

Here is my PDO code

```
$dbuser = "****"; 
$dbpass = "*****"; 

$unit = 5;
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=fdmamaint', $dbuser, $dbpass); 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM depunits');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($result) { 
    foreach($result as $row) {
    echo json_encode($row);
} 
$page = $_GET['page'];
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

} else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here is my code for the grid

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
      jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("initFontAwesome").jqGrid({
          pager:'#pager',
          url:'getUnits_1.php',
          datatype: "json",
          mtype: 'GET',
          height: 300,
          width: 1000,
          colNames:['Unit Id', 'Div Id', 'Title Org', 'Short Desc', 'Long Desc', 'Comments', 'Enabled'],
          colModel:[
                    {name:'unit_id',
                        index:'unit_id', 
                        width:40,
                        editable:true,
                        sortable:false, 
                        resizable:false,
                        align:"center", 
                        editoptions:{size:7,maxlength:6},
                        editrules:{required:true,number:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                    },
                    {name:'div_id',
                        index:'div_id', 
                        width:30,
                        editable:true,
                        sortable:false, 
                        resizable:false,
                        align:"center", 
                        edittype:'select',
                        editoptions:{size:4,maxlength:4},
                        editrules:{required:true,number:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                    },
                    {name:'title_org',
                        index:'title_org', 
                        width:60,
                        editable:true,
                        sortable:false, 
                        resizable:false,
                        edittype:'select',
                        formatter: 'select', 
                        //editoptions:{size:11,maxlength:11,value:{dataurl:getUnits.php}},

                        editrules:{required:true,number:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                    },
                    {name:'short_desc',
                        index:'short_desc', 
                        width:50,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        editoptions:{size:7,maxlength:10},                         
                    },
                    {name:'long_desc',
                        index:'long_desc', 
                        width:230,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        edittype:"textarea",
                        editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"30",maxlength:60},

                    },
                    {name:'unit_desc',
                        index:'unit_desc', 
                        width:230,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        edittype:"textarea",
                        editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"30",maxlength:60},
                        editrules:{required:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                    },
                    {name:'avail_ind',
                        index:'avail_ind',
                        width:40,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        align:"center",
                        edittype:"select",
                        editoptions:{value:"Y:Y;N:N"}
                    }
               ],

          pager: jQuery('#gridpager'),
          viewrecords: true,
          sortorder: "asc",
          sortname: "div_id",
          caption:"Unit Codes",
          editurl:'editUnits.php',
          toppager:true, 
          recordtext:'', 
          hidegrid:false,
          scroll:true,
          rowNum:"10000"

     });

     jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#grid_toppager', 
    {
        //clonetotop:true, 
        add:true,
        edit:true,
        view:true, 
        search:false, 
        del:false, 
        refresh:true
    },

    //$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{parameters},
              //prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);

    { // Edit form
        width:"auto",
        height:"auto",
        top:220,
        left:500,
        viewPagerButtons:false, //disables the arrows to next records
        topinfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required",
        resize:false
    },

    { // Add form
        width:"auto",
        height:"auto",
        top:220,
        left:500,
        topinfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required",
        resize:false,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
        closeAfterAdd: true   


   { //prmView
       // width:"auto",
       // height:"auto",
        top:220,
        left:460
   }


    );  

    $(".ui-separator","#grid_toppager").parent().remove(); //removes the vertical bar separator between standard buttons and custom navigator buttons

    $("#grid").closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
    .children("div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar")
    .css("text-align", "center")
    .children("span.ui-jqgrid-title")
    .css("float", "none")
    .css("font-size", "15px");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `getUnits_1.php` producing valid JSON?

Comment: Yes, I ran it through a validator and it came back as valid.